# Changing all cells colour except the cell i selected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

im new to iOS so have mercy xD.
I have a question, when i click in one cell, i want all the other cells text colour to be changed except the cell i selected, so the cell which i selected should not change text colour, just the other cells.

Comment: If you are using custom cell, just assign it some id (assuming cell has property "cellId") in cellForRowAtIndexPath and then in didSelectRowAtindexPath save this cellId, then reload [tableView reloadData] and in cellForRowAtIndexPath look if you have saved any id. If this id == cell.cellId then backgroundColor = green, else backgroundColor = blue

If you don't want to reloadData, there is more complicated solution, which I can post as a answer if you want to.

Comment: Will the colour you are changing the "other" cells to be different each time?  If not, why would you do it this way? Consider cells A B C and D. You select A and cells B C and D turn blue. You then select cell B - only cells A and B need to be updated (the ones being selected and deselected) as C and D are already blue.

Comment: I should not use a reloadData so It is more complicated